# Can't keep focus on a form field on Chrome/iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, focus

I have a simple web form (html 4), which works fine on most browsers except on Chrome on iOS.

The user has to click on the form field multiple times for the keyboard to stay. I do have Ads on the page.

How do I keep user's focus on the form field once they start to type?

The code snippet (pared down to what I think is relevant) is here:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>

<input name="FirstName" type="text" onKeyUp="processName()"  value="<?php echo $FirstName?>">
```

---

Thanks

Comment: This requires more information.

Comment: You need to provide a code snippet, and more about the languages you're leveraging to make this process occur in general.

Comment: Thanks. Added code snippet.